# How to turn ASP.NET web app with Razor Pages into an API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I have a blog website that I developed using ASP.NET with Razor Pages but, now I want to implement those blog posts on my personal portfolio website (Built with simple HTML, CSS and JS).

My first thought was that I now need to create an ASP.NET API from scratch to connect to the same blog database and then fetch it all with JS from my Portfolio Website.

Would I actually need to create a brand new API just for that or is there any way I can turn the existing blog into an API that can be called externally? Or somehow add an API endpoint that instead of rendering the pages just sends the Json data back to the client?

Comment: Did you try adding an API to your existing site? What went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Hi mason, no I haven't. I am still in the thinking process of how to approach it. I am not an expert on ASP .NET, still in the early days of it. I am migrating from Node.js to ASP .NET and wondering what would be the best approach.

So, would I just add a Controller to my existing blog app ? How would you approach adding an API as you suggested? Thanks again

Comment: I would take the approach of "just do it". There's nothing stopping you from trying to do as you suggested and see what kind of issues you run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. Add a Web API controller to your existing application and use that to return JSON
2. Add a [named handler method](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods) to an existing PageModel class that returns a `JsonResult` and call that from your AJAX method
3. If you are using .NET 6, [add a minimal API end point](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/358/using-minimal-apis-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages) to your application